# pytest fixtures for multiple test cases in parametrize decorator

Tags: python-3.x, testing, pytest, fixtures

I have a pytest fixture that takes in some parameters to get some test data stored in a test directory, used to create an object `foo`. `fixture1` and `fixture2` are fixtures defined in conftest.py.

What I would like to do is to test the many components of `Foo` for each test defined in the parametrize decorator, e.g. `assert foo.do_this() == 1, assert foo.do_something_else() == 2`, but I don't really want to include all these individual asserts in this `test_foo_components` function as it does not make sense to do so.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("cid, env, id, r, fixture1, fixture2",
                          [
                              (1, 2, 3, 4, None, None),
                              (2, 3, 4, 5, None, None),
                              (3, 4, 5, 6, None, None)
                          ],
                         ids=['test1',
                              'test2',
                              'test3'],
                         indirect=['fixture1', 'fixture2'])
def test_foo_components(cid, env, id, r, fixture1, fixture2):
    p = pd.read_parquet(...)
    t = pd.read_parquet(...)
    q = pd.read_parquet(...)
    c = pd.read_parquet(...)
    pm = pd.read_parquet(...)
    with open(...) as f:
        cs = pickle.load(f)

    timestamp = 0

    foo = Foo(p, t, q, c, pm, r, timestamp, cs, fixture1)
```

Ideally, I would like to 'fixturize' this `foo` object (see code block below), but this `foo` object is different on each test case (i.e. it depends on the parametrize inputs), I am not so sure how to write this in a neat way.

```
def test_foo_do_something(foo_fixture):
    assert foo_fixture.do_something() == 1
```

Update:

Fixtures 1 and 2 are the same for each test case, and there are potentially ~50 different instances of Foo, each of which has components that need to be tested.

This `foo_fixture` will be an instantiation of the Foo object, and this Foo instantiation will be unique for each test case, i.e. the majority of their components will be different (test case 1 `foo.do_something()` will be different to test case 2 `foo.do_something()`). However, assert in the above code block only allows for testing of static methods, but not for instance methods. With this updated info in mind, how would I test instance methods in a similar manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Instance of Foo decoupled from results that components expect

#### 1. Parametrize methods tested

You could add additional set of parameters to the test function, each representing a method of `Foo` that you want to test and the result you expect. Pytest would create and execute a **matrix of all possible combinations**.

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "cid, env, id, r, fixture1, fixture2",
    [(1, 2, 3, 4, None, None), (2, 3, 4, 5, None, None), (3, 4, 5, 6, None, None)],
    ids=["test1", "test2", "test3"],
    indirect=["fixture1", "fixture2"],
)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("method, expected", (("do_something", 1),))
def test_foo_components(cid, env, id, r, fixture1, fixture2):
    ...
    foo = Foo(p, t, q, c, pm, r, timestamp, cs, fixture1)

    assert getattr(foo, method)() == expected
```

#### 2. Parametrize Foo

**Fixtures could also be [parametrized](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#fixture-parametrize)** so any test that uses them would be run N times depending on the amount of parameters a fixture has. However, in your example you are using indirect fixtures which slightly complicates the things but it would still be possible to use them in a different manner if you rewrite them to work as callables instead of returning data directly.

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def fixture1():
    """
    Instead of returning a result, the fixture returns a function 
    that returns the result when called.
    """
    def _(arg):
        return ...

    return _

@pytest.fixture(
    params=[
        (1, 2, 3, 4, None, None),
        (2, 3, 4, 5, None, None),
        (3, 4, 5, 6, None, None),
    ]
)
def foo(request, fixture1, fixture2):
    cid, env, _id, r, f1, f2 = request.param
    f1 = fixture1(f1)
    f2 = fixture1(f2)
    ...
    return Foo(...)


def test_foo_do_something(foo):
    assert foo.do_something() == 1
```

**Note:** I personally wouldn't recommend option 1. I think you should strive to reorganise your code and **go with option 2** if possible. It's cleaner and it would be easier to further parametrize tests for each method/"component".

### Component results tied to Foo instances

If all those 50 different instances of `Foo` need to have a certain result defined for calling `Foo`'s component, then it gets tricky because you somehow need to match the instances with the results. The following example is a simple demonstration where N variations of `Foo` need to be matched by N expected results when calling `Foo.do_something()`.

- `params` in `@pytest.fixture` define each instance of `Foo` and thus control number of variations for each component's test function.
- `@pytest.mark.parametrize` contains only a single parameter of N results for each type of `Foo`.
- `component` fixture is what mixes variations of `Foo` with the expected result. Index of the `params` variation is used to do the matching.

```py
@pytest.fixture(params=[(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5, 6), ...])
def foo(request):
    cid, env, id, r = request.param
    ...
    return Foo(...), request.param_index 


@pytest.fixture()
def component(request, foo):
    return foo[0], request.param[foo[1]]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("component", ([1, 2, 3, ...],), indirect=True)
def test_foo_do_something(component):
    assert component[0].do_something() == component[1]
```

**Note:** This can easily get messy and lead to test failures or incorrect assertions. Imagine that adding a new set to `params` would require adding a new expected result to each component's test function, and re-ordering of `params` would wreak havoc in your tests. So, I think that you would need to come up with a different way of matching `Foo` instances with results.

Comment: why does the fixture need to be made a callable?

Comment: Because it's not going to be called by Pytest but instead you would call it yourself inside `foo` fixture function (see `fixture1(f1)`). However, if you could make it simpler and avoid using `fixture1` and `fixture2` in `foo`, it would be even better.

Comment: thanks, what if I have a long list of params? what would the best way to initialize the test cases?

Comment: *what if I have a long list of params?* That depends on what's your concern.

Comment: my concern is just on the overall cleanliness of the code, would it be better to define the test params in the global scope instead, as opposed to stuffing everything into params=[]?

Comment: If the list of params is manually defined, then IMHO it's better to have it inside the decorator definition but **if the list can be programmatically generated**, then it would make sense to have a builder function: `@pytest.fixture(params=foo_params())` You can then have that function wherever it makes sense. Just remember that the function cannot be a fixture and cannot use other fixtures because it's going to be called at the test collection stage.

Comment: Another thing is - in foo(request, fixture1, fixture2), whilst the other params cid, env, id, r are obviously different on each test case, fixtures 1 and 2 are actually the same across all test cases. With this in mind, can the foo fixture be further simplified?

Comment: Sure, just remove f1 and f2 then. You wouldn't even need to rewrite those fixtures the way I suggested.

Comment: I seem to have overlooked something - each component e.g. foo.do_something() will be different for all test cases, but however the test function restricts me to a single assert, how do I make it so that I can assert different outputs depending on the Foo?

Comment: My examples are for the case where instantiation of `Foo` is decoupled from the result when calling a particular component. If params of Foo affect the output of each component, then these two ultimately need to be tied together in some way. I might have some ideas but you would need to rewrite your question because your case is now getting fuzzy with your modifications, e.g. *list of params having to be defined elsewhere because it's apparently large* (and yet need to be tied to different component results), *fixture 1 and 2 possibly not needed*.

Comment: Just added an update to the question - thanks for all the help so far! - Yes, the instance methods/components of Foo need to be tied to their respective outputs for each Foo. Is there a 'common' pytest way of doing this? For static methods, your examples work perfectly.

Comment: See the new example of doing matching of different instances of `Foo` with expected results for components.

Comment: Would it be a better idea to restrict a single test file to a single instance of Foo? E.g. test1.py will only contain a particular instantiation of Foo, such that in test1.py I can assert the method/component tests to the actual expected output. However, I will end up with a lot of test files each with basically the same repetitive structure, the only difference being the inputs used to generate Foo.